# Google Map layer snapshot in iOS 17.2 is blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have developed an iOS app (way back with ObjectiveC) which creates an image of the current Google Map on the screen. I always have used this code, which ran fine:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.map.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[self.map.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Now I have the problem that since iOS 17.2 the image is empty (only the Google logo is shown, but no map information at all).

Does anybody know what the issue is?

Thx,
Danny

Comment: Are you by any means capturing the Google Map within the UI itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I am now using:

*[self.map drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.map.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];*

Code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.map.bounds.size);
[self.map drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.map.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```